# Script for pressing a keyboard key when a mouse button is pressed

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I'm trying to give me logitech mouse an order using lua script that when the primary key is pressed a key in the keyboard is also clicked until I stop holding the mouse button

I tried this one but it works perfectly with all the mouse buttons but no actions happens when I set it up for the primary key.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      PressKey("V")
   end
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 then
      ReleaseKey("V")
   end
end
```

any help?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default primary mouse button events are disabled.
You need to enable them explicitly.

```
local v_pressed

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then
      PressKey("V")
      v_pressed = true
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 and v_pressed then
      ReleaseKey("V")
   end
end
```

**UPDATE**
The script works only when ScrollLock LED is on.

Comment: what if I wanted to add a toggle key to toggle it on and off

Comment: Answer updated.  ScrollLock is the toggle key.